# Angular CLI prefixing pipes

Tags: angular, angular-cli

It just occurred to me that while the Angular CLI prefixes components and directives, it does not prefix pipes. From the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services), and by trial, it looks like it's not possible to configure the CLI to add prefixes to pipes. Does anyone know why that is? Does the reason why we prefix components and directives (to prevent naming collision in templates) not also apply to pipes?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the Angular team to have the exact answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the purpose of prefixing components and directives is to avoid naming collisions with DOM elements & element attributes (respectively). This is not needed for pipes because pipes are an angular specific implementation and do not clash with existing HTML 5 implementations.

Examples

- without the prefix `ng g c header` would generate an element `<header>` which clashes with the HTML header element. so we prefix it with `<app-header>`
- without the prefix `ng g d title` would generate an attribute `title` which clashes with the HTML title attribute. so we prefix it with `appTitle`
- finally `ng g p data` generates a pipe with name `data`. It is handled within angular specific code `{{myData | data}}` therefore it does not interfere with anything.

Comment: thanks for answering! I'm assuming that chances are low that a module imports two modules (that may even be third-party modules) in which both modules export a pipe under the same name? Or how would this situation be dealt with?

Comment: @SamHerrmann that's a good question. I think this is a rare case. I don't think there is an elegant way to handle this. One possible workaround would be to make a custom pipe that essentially "renames" the library pipe. Check out this stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xckrk?file=app%2Fmy-lib%2Fmy-lib.module.ts Not elegant, but it is a possible solution. Ideally the library would prefix their pipes if there is a chance of a name conflict.